# Exception raisedJava.lang.illegalargumentexception in android application

Tags: java, android, date

Hello Every body when I am trying to post date to database in android it is saying exception in such a way "Java.lang.illegalargumentexception" can any one help in fixation of this issue

& here is my Code

my calendar format code is..

```
   cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());


currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

// textView is the TextView view that should display it
tv.setText(currentDateTimeString);


SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a");



try {

    date = formatter.parse(currentDateTimeString);
    System.out.println("The date value is..."+date);
    System.out.println("Demo *******"+formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault());

System.out.println("Local Time is...."+sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

After clicking button it'll implements doing background action

& My posting to database code is..
 private class postAfterShake extends AsyncTask{

```
//Context context;
String jsonStr;



@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    String pinStr = "A5139";

    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

    String dstr = date.toString();


    //          http://192.168.3.125:8090/ShakeApp/rest/shake/shakeTime/pin/shakeTime1

    String loginUrl = "http://202.65.154.108:8080/ShakeApp/rest/shake/shakeTime/"+pinStr+ "/" +dstr;

    System.out.println("Login Url with test....."+loginUrl);

    jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(loginUrl, ServiceHandler.POST);

    Log.d("o  ", ">" +jsonStr);

    System.out.println(jsonStr);
```

And my Service handler class is...

```
         public class ServiceHandler {



static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public HttpEntity httpEntity;
public ServiceHandler() 
{

}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

public String makeServiceCaller(String url_category, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url_category, method, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }

        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        System.out.println(httpEntity);

        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

And exception what I am facing is...

```
           10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 66: http://202.65.154.108:8080/ShakeApp/rest/shake/shakeTime/A5139/Wed Oct 15 00:54:54 PST 2014
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at com.android.hits.charlesdeals.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:76)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at com.android.hits.charlesdeals.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:38)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at com.android.hits.charlesdeals.ShakeScreen$postAfterShake.doInBackground(ShakeScreen.java:197)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at com.android.hits.charlesdeals.ShakeScreen$postAfterShake.doInBackground(ShakeScreen.java:1)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-15 10:54:58.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32287):    ... 5 more
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception coming Java.lang.illegalargumentexception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386533/exception-coming-java-lang-illegalargumentexception)

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for the Exception?

Comment: Just a suggestion - don't use the calendar object.  Use jodatime instead.

Comment: @JasonBarrett  can you check my log trace

Answer (score 0):

You have an illegal character in the URL (:). Try encoding the URI properly.